# Python Flask do not send emit to the client

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, websocket

In my web application the user should upload a .csv file, my server read it, make some calculations and send back to the client the commands used in the calculation throw an emit.

Here is the python code used to receive the file:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            stream = io.StringIO(file.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
            csv_input = pd.read_csv(stream,sep=None,engine='python')
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            command_used = "csv_input = pd.read_csv('<your_file_name>',sep=None,engine='python')"
            socketio.emit('bot_command_line_response',{'data': command_used, 'count': session['receive_count']})
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',filename=filename))
    return render_template('index.html', async_mode=socketio.async_mode)
```

And in the client side I have the form used to upload the file:

```
<form id="upload" method = "POST" action='#'
     enctype = "multipart/form-data">
     <input type = "file" name = "file" id="file"/>
     <input type = "submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

And also the area on my webpage to show the command used:

```
socket.on('bot_command_line_response', function(msg) {
            $('#log_command_line').append('<br>' + $('<div/>').text('Command ' + msg.count + ': ' + msg.data).html());
        });
```

But, when I upload the file, the area does not show the command used.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Am a bit confused here, you are trying to upload the file through WebSocket or SocketIO, but then why do you have a POST Method validation(Done for HTTP requests) in your `upload_file()`  ? This will fail, and hence your client won't receive (the command you are talking about) an emit from that function.

If you really want to upload a file via WebSocket, you need to do it as a [write stream](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-resumable-video-uploader-in-nodejs--net-25445).

Comment: Now the upload file part is working, after my edit. The problem is that I am not receiving the socketio.emit() command on my client server. I should show the information that I supposed to receive by this command, but every time that I try to do from the regular route '/' nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solve my question:

1. When I upload the file for the first time, I save the name of the file in the **session** variable in the server. Every time that I need to use the file, I read it again.
2. I know this does not looks the best solution but at least it works.

Thank you guys.